# How to keep an input accepting python script running all day long after crontab started it?

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script that I want to run everyday at 7:00AM.
It has to keep running all day long until I stop it.
All it does it takes input and does something with it.
Crontab will run the script but after the first input the script ends.
How can I keep the script running?

Here is the crontab line

```
0 7 * * * python /home/test.py < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Here is the python code

```
i = ""
while (i <> "quit"):
   i = raw_input("Enter number: ")
   print "Number entered: " + i
print "Done"
```

The computer executing this script is running on ubuntu 18.04 LTS without graphical interface.

Here is the output at the command line when crontab starts executing the script.
I entered 1234 when prompted and then I got the command not found error.

```
testguy@ubuntumachine:~$ Enter Number: 1234
1234: command not found
testguy@ubuntumachine:~$
```

Comment: if you are running console-based python script how will you be able to give console input as it is executed by crontab?. If you have to perform some other task then for that you can run a script in the background.

Comment: The machine will be used only to run one program. One and only one python program. This program has to take a number as input all day long. The program runs fine when I execute the script from the command line. However, I want the program to get started automatedly at 7am. That is why I tried crontab, but if there is another way please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: check out the answer @Macrowriter

Answer (score 0):

> In this case , (if your OS is windows) you can use "Task Scheduler" .
>
> > so:
> >
> > > 1. go to "Task Scheduler" 2.select "create basic task" 3.make sure the Trigger part is set to daily at 7:00AM 4.select your script 5.finished!!

Comment: The machine in question runs on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I think crontab is the Task Scheduler for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to write input of python script into logs which need to be in the background. For that, you can use named pipe for user input and Linux crontab for scheduling of script. The input provided to the pipe will be redirected to python script.

Create named pipe using `mkfifo inputtext.txt`

Python script is like

```py
import sys
import os
i=" "
while True:
    i = sys.stdin.readline()
    if str(i).strip() == "quit":
        print("heheh exiting ")
        break
    elif str(i).strip() == "":
        continue
    print(i)
    with open("/home/file_timer/mylog.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write(i)
print("DONE")
```

On console, you can run the script in following way.

`/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/file_timer/consoletest.py < /home/file_timer/inputtext.txt`

Give input to pipe `cat > /home/file_timer/inputtext.txt` 
Input:

```
ttf
bnbn
chtre
uuuuut
opklb
quit
```

Output in mylog.txt file:

```
ttf
bnbn
chtre
uuuuut
opklb
```

Schedule this on Linux crontab

`30 09 * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/file_timer/consoletest.py < /home/file_timer/inputtext.txt`

And once it cron executes provide your input using named pipe. The process will be killed once you give `quit` as input to pipe.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. However, the input will be entered by a hand held scanner. Crontab is supposed to get the script started. The scanner enters the data as if it was a keyboard. The script is supposed to grab the input and do stuff with it. So the problem is to keep capturing the input.

Comment: yes, crontab is starting the script, but for input to script named pipe is there. till you add input to pipe script will always listen.